# Hide a part of listview and show after to click

Tags: android, android-listview, hint

I would like a hint about listView. What is the best way to show a part of one listview.
Summing up,I want to fill a listview with a title and a long text, but i do not want to show all text, just a part. However, i want to see all the textlong in a window, when a click on the item.

Title 1

textlongtextlong

textlongtextlong

textlongtextlong

textlongtextl...

Title 2

textlongtextlong

textlongtextlong

textlongtextlong
...

Comment: Are you looking for an http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can play with ellipsize and singleline attributes of textview.
So when first show (before click) set the ellipsize end and Singleline = true. 
Then after click one of the text field u can set the ellipsize to false and also the singleline. Hopely it can give an idea to accomplish your probs.